# SQL, Transferring a "SELECT" result list into another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three tables that I work with now.

```
agare (owner)

===================================================================================================
| FNR   |FASTIGHETSBETECKNING|     NAMN      |  CO  |UTADR1|    UTADR2      | POSTNR    | POSTORT |
===================================================================================================
|854684 |     Berryfarm 1    | Granny Smith  | NULL | NULL | Treebranch 12  | 765 18    |  Meadow |
|135864 |     Satinfarm 1    | Sara Lovelace | NULL | NULL | Satin Hill 12  | 376 49    |  Satina |
|468952 |     Fairyhill 7    | Paula Green   | NULL | NULL |  Oaktree 12    | 468 67    |  Fairys |
|468952 |     Fairyhill 6    | Paula Green   | NULL | NULL |  Oaktree 12    | 468 67    |  Fairys |
```

---

```
fastighet (Estate that the owner owns)
===============================================================
| FNR  |FASTIGHETSBETECKNING|BELAGENHETSADRESS|POSTNR|POSTORT |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|854684|     Berryfarm 1    |  cherryroad 14  |759 45|Grassmow|
|135864|     Satinfarm 1    |  Satineroad 69  |136 89|Satiniqe|
|468952|     Fairyhill 7    |  fairysroad 17  |845 97|Birdsfal|
|468952|     Fairyhill 6    |  fairysroad 19  |962 63|Flowersy|
===============================================================
```

---

```
users (registrated user)
========================
|username|   adress    |
------------------------
| 854684 |             |
| 135864 |             |
| 468952 |fairysroad 17|
| 468952 |fairysroad 19|
========================
```

I can find people with one Estate with:

`SELECT FNR FROM agare,users WHERE FNR IN (SELECT FNR FROM fastighet, users WHERE FNR=username AND adress IS NULL GROUP BY FNR HAVING COUNT(FNR) < 2) AND users.username=FNR GROUP BY FNR`

witch retuns a list with meny people with the adress field blank

but I want to fill the blank adress field in users with the data from fastighet.

I have tried to use `INSERT into users (adress) SELECT "something"` but I need help

Regards Martin

Comment: Here's a http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9834b where anyone can play around. Your query doesnt' work and it's not even clear to me how the tables are related. Get it working and explain better, otherwise this question is not answerable.

Comment: By switching = "" to IS NULL makes is happen in sqlfiddle

Comment: What? I don't get what you're talking about. And I meant, that your query doesn't work at all. Just execute the select part, not the insert into. You're missing a FROM clause, where username = select... is missing parantheses. It's not clear if the group by belongs to the subquery or not.... and so on.

Comment: The table agare (owner) shows the person who own an estate and where that person lives, the fastighet (Estate) shows the Estate name and location, the table user is the owner that have register his/hers interest in a project with the house as a participant

Comment: I have now corrected the Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still struggling a bit understanding your question, but could it be that you're after an update rather than an insert?

See the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bc46/2/0).

I updated the users table with the adress of the fastighet table where for each FNR there's only one entry. Did I understand it right?

```
UPDATE users u INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM fastighet GROUP BY FNR HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) f 
ON u.username = f.FNR
SET u.adress = f.BELAGENHETSADRESS;
```

Comment: Yes, when I look at your link, I will do what I want. Shall try that, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try running an `UPDATE` on the users table by using the values of the fastighet table something similar to the below:

```
UDPATE a
SET address = b.FASTIGHETSBETECKNING
FROM users a
JOIN fastighet  b on a.username = b.fnr
WHERE a.address is null OR a.address = ''
```

Comment: you have to join agare (owner) as there are mulitiple entries for FNR and have to consider FASTIGHETSBETECKNING field too.

Comment: good point, hadn't even noticed that. It makes it indeed more difficult as for each record you need to check whether or not it already exists.

Comment: Thank you JanR and vijay, I will try that

Comment: b.FASTIGHETSBETECKNING should be BELAGENHETSADRESS. But where whill my condition fit with "only for those with 1 estate)?